# Abuse of notation in the chain rule

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, notation, chain-rule

I have a function:  $f: \mathbb{R}^p \to \mathbb{R}^n$. Now let's define the functions $x_i : \mathbb{R}^p \to \mathbb{R}$, and hence we can define the function  $\phi : (u_1,..., u_p) \to (x_1(u_1,...,u_p), ..., x_p(u_1,...,u_p))$

Then my book is defining the partial derivative of $f \circ \phi$ at $u_j$ as

> $$\frac{\partial f\circ \phi}{\partial u_j} = \sum_{i = 1}^p \frac{\partial x_i}{\partial u_j} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}$$

But it doesn't mean anything to take the partial derivative at a function!?  So $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}$ doesn't make sense, since $x_i$ is a function; I mean we can't calculate the partial derivative at a function.
For example it doesn't mean anything to say $\frac{\partial (x^2+y^2)}{\partial xy}$, right?

So I guess this is an abuse of notation and that the right formula is

> $$\frac{\partial f\circ \phi}{\partial u_j} = \sum_{i = 1}^p \frac{\partial x_i}{\partial u_j} \frac{\partial f}{\partial a_i}$$

where the $a_i$ are independent variables and not functions!

Am I correct?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, the traditional notation is abusive.  If you define $\frac{\partial f}{\partial a_i}$ to be $\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0} \frac{ f(a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_i+\epsilon, \ldots, a_p) -f(a_1, a_2, \ldots a_p)}{\epsilon}$, then your definition of the chain rule is fine.

Comment: I had a very good teacher for vector calculus, and he pointed out the abusive notation.  I think all vector calculus teachers should explain how the traditional statement of chain rule for functions between multidimensional vector spaces has abusive notation.

Comment: @irchans Thank you! But there is still something that fills strange to me. For example let $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function. Then we can defined a new function $g(u,v) = f(u+v, uv)$. Using the chain rule we have : $\partial / \partial u = \partial / \partial x + v \partial / \partial y$. But now it means that : $(\partial f/ \partial x + v \partial  / \partial y)u= 1$ right ? But for me : $\partial u / \partial x = 0$ ? since there isn't any occurence of $x$ in $u$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is just a mild abuse of notation.  Consider the 1-dimensional case.  We could say that $f(x)$ is a differentiable function and $x(t)$ is differentiable.  Then $(f\circ x)'(t)=f'(x(t))x'(t)$.

Ideally it is better to use a different letter for functions and say that if $f(x)$ is differentiable and $u(t)$ is differentiable then $(f\circ u)'(t)=f'(u(t))u'(t)$.  But it is no big deal.

Comment: Great thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment:

We could also use the notation $D_i f$ for the $i$th partial derivative of $f$. Then this chain rule formula could be written as 
$$
D_j F(u) = \sum_{i=1}^p D_i f(x(u)) D_j x_i(u)
$$
where $u = (u_1,\ldots,u_p)$ and $x(u) = (x_1(u),\ldots, x_p(u))$ and $F(u) = f(x(u))$.

Comment: Thank you, it's indeed more clear to write it this say since it avoids confusion and the formula is also less scary.