# Chain rule, two different interpretations, two different results

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, chain-rule

I have a function $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$. So we can write $f(x,y)$ where $x$ and $y$ are independant variables.
Now we define the function $g(u,v) = f(u+v, uv)$.

Using the chain rule we have :

> $$\frac{\partial g}{\partial u} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + v \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$$
> $$\frac{\partial g}{\partial v} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + u \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$$
>
> Thus we have :
>
> $$\frac{\partial}{\partial v} \frac{\partial g}{\partial u} = \left ( \frac{\partial }{\partial x} + u \frac{\partial }{\partial y} \right) \left ( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + v \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \right)$$
>
> But here I have a problem when developing this expression. Indeed we have : $\frac{\partial v}{\partial v} = 1$ so I should expect that :
>
> $$\left ( \frac{\partial }{\partial x} + u \frac{\partial }{\partial y} \right) v = 1$$

Yet for me we have :
$\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = 0$ since there isn't any occurence of $x$ in $v$. So I get that : $(\frac{\partial }{\partial x} + u \frac{\partial }{\partial y} )v = 0 \ne 1. $

So what is the problem here ? I think it comes from the fact that $x$ depends on $u$, but normally this shouldn't be the case right ? I mean $x$ and $y$ are defined at the  beginning there are just the composant of the function $f$, and they are independant. Moreover if $x$ depends an $u$ it would mean that $f$ is a function of $u$, but it doesn't mean anything to differentiate at a function, moreover as said [earlier](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3090183/abuse-of-notation-in-the-chain-rule/3090194#3090194) $x$ and $y$ doesn't depend on anything.

Hence what is really going on here ?

Thank you !

Comment: Why does $\frac{\partial g}{\partial v} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + u \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ imply $\frac{\partial}{\partial v} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + u \frac{\partial}{\partial y}$?

Comment: $v$ isn't a function so how are you taking the partial derivative of it with respect to itself??

Comment: @angryavian Thank you. I don't really know actually... But then I don't see what $\partial / \partial v$ is equal to ?

Comment: @Displayname it implicitily defined the function $ v \mapsto v$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You miss the term $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ obtained from deriving $v\times \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ by $v$.

$\begin{align}\displaystyle \frac{\partial}{\partial v}\frac{\partial g}{\partial u}
&=\frac{\partial}{\partial v}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + v \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)
\\\\\displaystyle &=\frac{\partial}{\partial v}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)+v\frac{\partial}{\partial v}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}
\\\\\displaystyle &=\left(\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} + u\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}\right)+v\left(\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y} + u\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}\right)+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\end{align}$

Comment: Thank you. But to go from the second equality to the third you use the fact that : $\frac{\partial}{\partial v} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + u\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ right ?

Comment: also at the beginning it should be $g$ instead of $f$ if I am not mistaken.

Comment: I do not really use the operator equality as you write. I'm just considering the chain rule. Think of it as $\frac{\partial}{\partial v}(f_x'(u+v,uv))$ when the variables appears in $f_x'$ it is easier to see what's going on, and why the operator equality won't work for $\frac{\partial}{\partial v}(vf_y'(u+v,uv))$

Comment: Oh I see. It makes a lot more sens now, and I guess there is no other simple form for : $\frac{\partial}{\partial v}$ so you need to use the chain rule. Thank you !